# How to replace empty string between two patterns

Tags: linux, replace, sed, vi

I have a file with below pattern. I want to replace all occurrences starting with "id" and ending with first occurance of , with empty string in vi editor
"id": 797979,

Comment: Honestly, this might be easier to do with sed: `sed -i s/\"id.*\,//g filename`. Test the regex on a copy of the file first though, since I haven't.

Comment: I tried your recommended command but it is deleting followed text after , till end of the line. I do want to remove text till , not followed text.

Comment: say I have a line in my file 
{"element1": "value","id": 0, "rlrmr": "sdfs", "element2": "sdfaf"} 

when I execute "sed -i s/\"id.*\,//g filename" it making empty text after , as well. 

{"element1": "value",

Comment: please, post file data sample

Answer (score 1):

with sed

```
sed 's/"id"[^,]*,//g'
```

you have to watch for greedy match when there is more than one comma on the line (some other answers above didn't)

Answer (score 0):

Tested this sed out on the sample provided in comments and it works as long as the `"id:xyz,` pattern appears only once per line.

```
sed -i 's/\(.*\)\("id.*,\)\(.*\)/\1\3/' filename
```